# some icons changed to squares

Tags: 16.04, icons, unity-tweak-tool, layout

In my Ubuntu 16.04 some icons have changed into squares (at the beginning everything was fine). I've changed all fonts into roboto thin via tweak tool. I've installed two packages with icons for Sublime Text, however when i removed them nothing changed. I'll put some images for examples:

In buttons for changing layout from grid to list are squares.

[image]

In weather App all icons that should show weather conditions are squares.

[image]

How do i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried taking taking it back to the default font, does it change back?

Comment: @George - tried with reboot. Didn't work